# How to use Hosting Controller for SwiftUI in existing Storyboard Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: swift, swiftui, storyboard, tabbarcontroller, uihostingcontroller

I'm trying to use a Hosting Controller to include a SwiftUI View in an existing Storyboard Tab Bar Controller.  I already connected a Hosting View Controller to the Tab Bar Controller on Storyboard using the Relationship Segue.  Below is what I tried from reading other posts, but all I get is a black screen.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SingleSearchHost: UIHostingController<SingleSearch>{
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder, rootView: SingleSearch())
    }
}
```

Comment: In interface builder, did you set the hosting controller’s class to SingleSearchHost?

Comment: @Adam omg I can't believe I missed that!  Thank you so much!  Now it works totally fine!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my problem was to assign the class to the Host Controller in the Storyboard identity inspector.  Thank you @Adam for answering this question!